# How can I change the default view of the search results in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, explorer

In Windows 10, when I execute a search through Explorer it returns an unwieldy list with large icons, with the results sorted in an unhelpful way. I always need to change the View and click on the appropriate column to get a usable result list.

This is annoying and I'd like to change this behavior, at the very least so the initial list doesn't display large icons (which take up a ridiculous amount of screen estate and result in me seeing only a dozen or so results).

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done, but (rather amazingly) not by customizing the View through some menu, but... by executing a Registry change!

The solution can be found on [the WinHelpOnline site](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/search-results-content-view-fix-details-windows-10/), and is as simple as **creating a .REG file** with the following contents and then executing it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;Fixes search results defaults to Content view.
;Sets Details view as default search results view for Generic folders.

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU]

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{7fde1a1e-8b31-49a5-93b8-6be14cfa4943}]
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004
```

Because this involves the Explorer, you'll need to log off and log on again after applying it to see it applied.

Answer (score 5):

BCdotWEB's answer is fantastic. I just wanted to pull some other helpful information out of that [linked article](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/search-results-content-view-fix-details-windows-10/) in case it ever goes down. If you want the "Details" view for all folder types--not just "Generic" folders--use this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;Fixes search results defaults to Content view.
;Sets Details view as default search results view for Generic, Music, Videos, Documents folders.

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU]

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags]

;Generic Search Results
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{7fde1a1e-8b31-49a5-93b8-6be14cfa4943}]
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004

;Pictures Search Results
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{4dcafe13-e6a7-4c28-be02-ca8c2126280d}]
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004

;Music Search Results
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{71689ac1-cc88-45d0-8a22-2943c3e7dfb3}]
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004

;Documents Search Results
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{36011842-dccc-40fe-aa3d-6177ea401788}]
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004

;Videos Search Results
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{ea25fbd7-3bf7-409e-b97f-3352240903f4}]
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004
```